# linux bash tool to read property from property file

Tags: linux, bash

I want to be able to run a command to get a property from a property file.  So if my properties file is property.props and has

```
username=dsollen
password=letMeIn
linux-skills=newb
```

I would like to have a *quick* way to pull out the property to pipe into other commands.  so

```
 ./myProgram -v -p `getProp property.props password`
```

or something like that; not sure I used the ` right, but that's a different newb linux question for later :)

I know I can do this with a combination of grep and cut/awk/sed/whatever, but I'm wondering if there is an already existing tool that 'knows' how to read common property file formats and does something like this?  If not I could write something to add into my scripts folder, just don't want to reinvent the wheel if a better wheel already exists.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/conffile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **[gvar](https://github.com/arturoherrero/gvar)** to do the work. I'm the author by the way.

From the source code, this is the interesting part for you:

```
get_variable() {
  < "$FILE" grep -w "$1" | cut -d'=' -f2
}
```

Comment: You may want to check your code with shellcheck.net.

Comment: my 5 second scan of the home page suggests this is for global variables only.  can it be used to simply return a variable without making it global?

Comment: @dsollen The function he posted doesn't make it a variable, it just returns the value. You can do whatever you want with the function.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your properties keys are unique, if so then the following might be a way:

```
grep -w "$1" <property.props
```

or to get the value

```
(grep -w "$1" | cut -d= -f2) <property.props
```

Where `$1` is the key.

Comment: You should use `grep -w` otherwise you have a collision if you have `pass` and `password` in the file and you grep for `pass`.

Comment: Ah that's a good TIL, thanks! :D

Comment: This would be perfect if it worked for values split over multiple lines with `\\`

Answer (score 0):

Look, just define in your .bashrc a function:

```
getProp() {
  awk -F "=" "/^$2=/ {print "'$2'"; exit; }" $1
}
```

And use it in your shell:

```
$ getProp property.pros password
letMeIn

$ getProp property.pros linux-skills
newb
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.